# How to limit width of an element with word-wrap property?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a border bottom under a text (sample below with "Internal Stakeholder Communications"), and the word break causes the border to be too big for the new width. What is the best practice for improving this CSS implementation?

```css
 .cont {
 width: 250px;
 }
 
 .tab-title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    color: #1573a4;
    opacity: .89;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: .9;
    letter-spacing: -.3px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.tab-title-active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1573a4;
    color: #1573a4;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: .9;
    letter-spacing: -.3px;
 }
 .tabs-container div:last-child {
 text-align: right;
}
 
.tabs-container {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: .5px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="tabs-container">
    <div><h3 class="tab-title">Tab 1</h3></div>
        <div><h3 class="tab-title tab-title-active">Internal Stakeholder Communications</h3></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem ... the border width isn't related to the text, it's related to the container. The container is stretching to fit the 250px you defined in .cont class.

Comment: Hi, the 250 is just to emulate the behaviour when the widow/viewport is smaller. You can see that the blue border on the right is not following the text..

Comment: And in what exact way to you want it to be “following the text”? Is it supposed to be as wide as “Internal Stakeholder”, or only as wide as “Communications”? The former you could perhaps achieve using an inline-block element, but the latter is not really possible with current day CSS. It could perhaps be emulated somehow by wrapping “Communications” into its own element and applying the border to that, but this will then again likely break in situations where there is more space available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `max-width` to  `.tab-title-active` or `tab-title` class to ensure that the width does not exceed a center value.

```css
.cont {
 width: 250px;
 }

 .tab-title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    color: #1573a4;
    opacity: .89;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: .9;
    letter-spacing: -.3px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.tab-title-active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1573a4;
    color: #1573a4;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: .9;
    letter-spacing: -.3px;
    max-width: 150px;
 }
 .tabs-container div:last-child {
 text-align: right;
}

.tabs-container {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: .5px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="tabs-container">
    <div><h3 class="tab-title">Tab 1</h3></div>
        <div><h3 class="tab-title tab-title-active">Internal Stakeholder Communications</h3></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What about bigger screen? If you set `max-width`, then the `tab-title-active` always will be wrapped into two lines. I think it is not a solution of @Micky problem.

Answer (score -1):

```css
 .cont {
 width: 250px;
 }
 
 .tab-title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    color: #1573a4;
    opacity: .89;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: .9;
    letter-spacing: -.3px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.tab-title-active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1573a4;
    color: #1573a4;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: .9;
    letter-spacing: -.3px;
 }
 .tabs-container div:last-child {
 text-align: right;
}
 
.tabs-container {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: .5px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="tabs-container">
    <div><h3 class="tab-title">Tab 1</h3></div>
        <div style="max-width: 57%;"><h3 class="tab-title tab-title-active">Internal Stakeholder Communications</h3></div>
      </div>
```

Simple add a max-width: 57%; to div that contain your text

Comment: How is your answer different from the one posted earlier?

Comment: my solution, with the percentage is more responsive.